# How to restore a .sql pg_dump on PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, psql, pgadmin, pg-dump, pg-restore

I have a dump from an SQL database, it is a `.sql` file. I tried restoring it in pgAdmin but I get an error:

```
pg_restore: error: input file appears to be a text format dump. Please use psql.
```

Then I tried using the `psql` CLI but it just lists my users and it doesn't show any error or restores anything. I tried `psql` with the command

```
psql grana < c:\dump-grana.sql
```

and got the result on the image:
[image: psql_output]

Also when I try to use the command `psql -U [user] -d [dbname] -1 -f <filename>.sql` it returns the same as the image above.

Answer (score 1):

### You're trying to use `psql` from inside `psql`

The picture you show is from *inside* psql. Your command is supposed to call it from the *outside*. Type `\q` and hit enter to exit `psql`, then use your command from outside it. Currently, `psql` is reading your input and:

1. `psql grana < c:` gets ignored. It's accepted as unfinished statement without verifying it yet
2. `\du` gets executed as [`\du` meta-command](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMANDS) describing available users
3. `mp-grana.sql` gets ignored as accidental parameters to `\du`
4. Your next lines or commands are accepted the same way, but only meta-commands get executed: until `psql` gets a `;` from you, it assumes you're still typing out some long and strange set of statements and commands. It won't try to verify anything else than the meta-commands until you finish.

If you've tried that from ***outside*** `psql` and it's still happening, it means you likely overwrote the contents of the file with its path by accident and now `psql` is receiving literal `c:\dump-grana.sql` from inside the file. In that case, if you created the dump yourself, you'll need to [re-do it](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html). Otherwise, get a fresh copy and try again: your command should work just fine as long as the contents of the `.sql` file make sense.

Answer (score 0):

If you have used the following `pg_dump` to create the dump file

```
pg_dump -Fc -b $database > $database.dump
```

Then use the following restore command:

```
pg_restore --verbose --clean --if-exists --exit-on-error --dbname $database $database.dump --single-transaction
```

You will have to expose the following variables

```
# Postgres restore
export PGPORT=${POSTGRES_PORT}
export PGHOST=${POSTGRES_HOST}
export PGUSER=${POSTGRES_USERNAME}
export PGPASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
```